# PHP and GZIP strange behavior

Tags: php, gzip

I have two files:
In this way everything Works well:

test.php

```
<?php
$json = array();
$json['Result'][] = array("Result"=>"Hello World");
$data = json_encode($json);
$gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
echo $gzdata;
?>
```

Result:

```
{"Result":[{"Result":"Hello World"}]}
```

But if I add an include, not matter what:

```
<?php
include_once('DataBase.php');

$json = array();
$json['Result'][] = array("Result"=>"Hello World");
$data = json_encode($json);
$gzdata = gzencode($data, 9);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
echo $gzdata;
?>
```

DataBase.php

```
<?php    
class DataBase{
public static function getColor(){return 'red';}
}
?>
```

Result:

```
RRW
```

It doesn't work at all!!

Anyone can help me :(

Comment: Enable error reporting

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a specific problem. That's a vague observation.

Comment: Please don't use ?> end tags, you don't need them for plain php files and they may cause problems, cause everything before <?php and after ?> will be printed out to the browser. As you want to send a header() this might be cause the huge problem for you.

Comment: It Works!! It was ?>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at the end of the PHP file:

?>